# How to determine if method is called using Python mock but does not replace the function body?

Tags: python, python-mock

There are plenty of examples that shows how to assert a method has been called using Mock, eg. `assert_called_with()`, but all of them involve replacing the method with Mock instance.

What I want is a little bit different, I want the function to be executed normally without its body replaced, but still want to assert if the function has been called.

eg.

```py
def dosomething(...)
    # creates records that I will test later on.
    ....

def execute():
    ....
    dosomething()
```

in my tests

```py
def test_a(...):
    with patch(dosomething...) as mocked:
        execute()
        mocked.assert_called_with()
```

I know I can test against the records that `dosomething()` creates instead. Yes I agree, but I just want to find out if it's possible to do per as my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Mock`'s `wraps` kwarg and pass it the original method.

For example,

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> def hi(name): print('hi', name)
>>> mock_hi = mock.Mock(wraps=hi)
```

The wrapped function is called by the mock.

```
>>> mock_hi('Bob')
hi Bob
```

But it's still a mock that remembers calls.

```
>>> mock_hi.call_args_list
[call('Bob')]
```

---

Recall that `patch()` will pass along extra kwargs to the `Mock` it makes, so you can use the `wraps` argument here too. For example,

```
>>> with mock.patch('builtins.float', wraps=float) as mock_float:
...     x = float('inf')
...     print(x)  # If we hadn't wrapped, x would be a mock.
...     print(mock_float.call_args_list)
...
inf
[call('inf')]
```

Comment: It's too bad there's no `autowrap` option that's analogous to `autospec`.